# SAS Script delete dataset older 4 years?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

[I have eight folders(library) in the archive disk that have tables with name as "tablename_YYYYMM".I want to write a script which loops through all the folders on the disk and deletes tables older than 4 years. Table deletion should be done on the date implied by the filename (dataset name)and individual querying of the dataset is not required. the deleted dataset name and deletion time is stored. I have attached the tables structure.
I have the below code but it didn't worked as expected.
[Image of table structure]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llC83.png

```
     %macro check();
    options mlogic;
    PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK._ALL_ OUT=contents NOPRINT;
    RUN;
    
    proc sort data=work.contents;
    by memname;
    run;
    
    DATA work.deleted;
      length libname $15. time 8;
      format time datetime20.;
      RETAIN libname memname time;
        SET contents(KEEP=LIBNAME MEMNAME) end=eof;
        by memname
        
        where intnx('year',today(),-4,'s') < 
    input(scan(memname,-1,'_')||'01',?yymmdd8.) and 
   length(scan(memname,-1,'_'))=6;
        time = datetime();
        if first.memname;
        if _n_ = 1 then call execute('proc sql;');
        call execute(catx(' ', 'drop table', catx('.', libname, 
    memname), ';'));
        if eof then do;
          call execute('quit;');
          end;
      RUN;  
    RUN;
    %mend;
```

Comment: Do you mean a SAS program?  Is the archive disk a single directory?  A nested directory tree? Multiple independent trees? How do you want to determine the AGE of the data? 
 Do you want to do it by file creation date?  Metadata SAS has written in the dataset? Some date variable in the data?  Some data value encoded in the directory or dataset name?  What is a "cluster member"?

Comment: I would recommend using bash, command prompt, or PowerShell for this that checks the file date for sas7b* files and removes them. SAS would be a more difficult tool to implement this.

Comment: Does the date implied by the filename (dataset member name) have anything to do with your decision on whether to delete the file or not?  It will be much easier to decide based on the name rather than having to read the contents of each dataset to decide.  If you do have to query each dataset what is the name of the variable that has the date? Is it the same in every dataset?  What is the criteria for deletion? Any value that is too old? All values are too old?

Comment: You don't want to delete datasets? You want to delete observations from the datasets?  How do you know which variable to check?  Do the datasets all have the exact some structure?

Comment: @Tom so do i need to use the code which you gave or it will be different

Comment: You need something completely different to delete observations.  Is the variable name the same in every dataset?  Show an example of a few observations from one of the datasets where some will stay and some will go.  Do you want to soft-delete the observations or build a new dataset with just the remaining observations (so it uses less space).

Comment: Yes the variable name is same in every datset.
Web_Id   Serial_No gt_product  Acc_Id    t_date
a7bf70be 4257535 .         .      28/04/2017
a7ecdce9 8538962 .         .      28/04/2019
4f8d68c6 4474502 .         4701925  28/04/2021
78672efa 9042317 .         .      28/04/2023
Above are few obs in which t_date obs 2017 and 2019 needs to be deleted as they older
than 4 years from todays date. 
Yes i want to soft delete the observations and not build a new dataset.
And yes datasets contain the same variables

Comment: @Tom The program should calculate the difference of 4 years from any given time in the future as this programs need to be run periodically

Comment: @tom Hi tom the scenarios changed. would you be kind to help me out again

Comment: Update the question to include examples so it it clear what you want to happen.  You still have not clarified what a CLUSTER is and how it could have an age.

Comment: @tom i have updated the questions to include all the details. Please check and tell if anything else is required

Comment: Define how you want to determine the AGE.  As I asked before in my first comment.

Comment: If you want to test by the date that SAS considers the dataset to have been made use the MODATE variable in the PROC CONTENTS output (notice that is a DATETIME value and not a DATE value).  If you want to use more complex logic to decide which datasets to delete then I would separate the step that makes the decision from the one executes the DROP statement.  It will be easier to debug your logic that way.

Comment: How to check if the dataset has a date suffix is already covered in the answer.  Try it yourself and if you get stuck ask a new question that includes the code you tried and in what way it did not work.

Comment: @Tom hi to can you please verify the above code as its not deleting the expected dataset

Comment: Is the part after the _ in the dataset name 4 digits or 6?  Your where clause is expecting it to be 4 characters in one place and 6 in another.

Comment: @tom its 6 digits

Comment: @Tom like YYYYMM(202306, 202205,202212)

Comment: @Tom i have attached the table structure image which shows how the table names are

Comment: @tom even after changing where clause it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

**To delete OBSERVATIONS**

Make a libref pointing to the archive directory.  Get the list of members (dataset names) that have the variable T_DATE. Generate an SQL delete statement for each one.

```
libname archive 'some directory name';
proc contents data=archive._all_ out=contents noprint; run;
data _null_;
  set contents end=eof;
  where upcase(name) = 'T_DATE';
  if _n_=1 then call execute('proc sql;');
  call execute(catx(' ','delete from',catx('.',libname,memname)
       ,"where intnx('year',t_date,4,'same') < today()",';'));
  if eof then call execute('quit;');
run;
```

**To delate DATASETS**

Make a libref pointing to the archive directory.  Get the list of members that have the YYMM suffix on them. Convert the suffix to an actual date.  Then delete the ones were the date is more than 4 years old.

```
libname archive 'some directory name';
proc contents data=archive._all_ out=contents noprint; run;
data _null_;
  set contents(keep=libname memname) end=eof;
  by memname;
  where length(scan(memname,-1,'_'))=4 
    and intnx('year',today(),-4,'s') < input(scan(memname,-1,'_')||'01',?yymmdd6.)
  ;
  if first.memname;
  if _n_=1 then call execute('proc sql;');
  call execute(catx(' ','drop table',catx('.',libname,memname),';'));
  if eof then call execute('quit;');
run;
```

Then just use what ever operating system tools you have to schedule the job to run when ever you need.